# How add css class with Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

```
<div class="generic_layout_container layout_ride_ridespec">
</div>
```

How to programmicaly add an extra class or one more property with existing class to above div.
I would like out put as follows

```
<div class="generic_layout_container layout_ride_ridespec example_class">
</div>
```

Please excuse `id/name` solution, there is little difficulty to add an id or name for above element.
Thanks

Answer (score 17):

MooTools does have an [addClass()](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aaddClass) method.  Eg:

HTML

```
<div id="myElement" class="testClass"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$('myElement').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: +1 Heh, but surely my answer is shorter and easier to read :p

Comment: @karim79 your answer is totally valid!

Comment: @YannisDran it would appear he deleted it.