# Add class to a parent of an element with MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, addclass

Let's say we have this:

```
<article>
 <div id="zoo">...</div>
</article>
```

I want to be able to add a class to `<article>` using MooTools.

If I was using Jquery, I would use the following code:

```
$("div#zoo").parent().addClass("blog");
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/yannisdran/Eq2tY/)

resulting this in the DOM:

```
<article class="blog">
```

However, I need it in MooTools. How do I have to express this code?

Comment: Isn't it somewhere in the mootools DOC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add css class with Mootools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211881/how-add-css-class-with-mootools) **||** [See Also: MooTools Doc|addClass](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:addClass)

Comment: agree with @adeneo, not to  mention the fact ... shhh ... jQuery is just plain better! I know this isn't the place and the argument could go on forever, but lets face facts, more people use jQuery than any other JS lib worldwide and there's a reason why ... IT'S BETTER!

Comment: sure JQuery is better I wouldn't argue on that. I was asked to use MooTools on a specific instance, so I couldn't avoid it.
However, it is not duplicate: the one indicated is just an addClass function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
       $('zoo').getParent().addClass('blog');
```

And here is the fiddle...
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hWQa/1/)